# Where is mileage stored? - 2007 Nissan Murano

Tags: nissan, mileage, instrument-cluster, murano

I have a 2007 Nissan Murano, and the engine temperature reading is all wonky. It routinely pings at the top but bounces right down if you tap it. I had the dealer check it out, and they said the actual thermometer in the engine is fine, and they recommend just living with it, because the cost of a new cluster from them is around 1500$.

But I'd like to be able to trust my temperature reading, just in case. So I'm looking around online at getting a used one (for much cheaper), and I'm just wondering about the mileage reading. From what I can find online, some cars store it in the cluster, others store it in the computers, but I can't find anything saying one way or the other for the Murano.

Does anyone know if the Murano stores its current mileage reading in the cluster, and thus will be inaccurate after changing it, or if it stores it in the computers?

Comment: Most modern vehicles store the mileage in several places, is my understanding. There are devices which can update the mileage, but if not done right, the mileage will revert back to its original value. You can't just change the mileage very easily. Not even sure a dealership can do that for you.

Comment: So, keep all the details, old odo reading, date changed, new odo reading when fitted and even keep the old odo. If you then sell it the « new » owner will follow the total mileage. If you don’t sell then what is the problem - you know when to service it...

Comment: The mileage is stored in the Instrument cluster l. It can be corrected on replacement to match original Miles tho this is only done by specialists. I usually include it when ever I sell replacement clusters

Answer (score 1):

Odometer tampering legislation is the result of rolling back mileage in older gear driven mechanical odometers where illegal changes to odometers occurred among used car dealers, individuals and anyone wanting to lower odometer numbers. Electronics abides by anti tampering laws to make it virtually impossible to alter odometer mileage. Some vehicles like GM store this in the body control module. If the bcm fails, a dealer with authorized scantool will program the replacement bcm with the last odometer reading on the gauge cluster. Used bcms retain mileage and cannot be altered in compliance with anti tampering laws so the owner using it might have an issue when selling the vehicle with the new owner registering the vehicle with the state dmv. Many owners aren't concerned about mileage as they keep their vehicles and just want a functional bcm. The same if odometer mileage is stored in the ecm in other brands. If I'm not mistaken, a chip in the gauge cluster simply counts up from signals sent from  the bcm to update the electronic odometer display. If a used bcm has less mileage than the odo display, the display appears frozen until the bcm values increments and surpasses the displayed mileage when it resumes counting up. A used bcm with higher values simply updates the display to reflect the value stored in the bcm. All complying with tampering laws against altering mileage.
You can always ask your local Nissan dealer service department's technician for clarification.